# Type hints for Python 3 dictionary containing required and un-determined optional keys

Tags: python, dictionary, type-hinting, python-typing

If I have a dictionary which contains required and but also arbitrary optional keys, how should I type this dictionary?

Example:

```
Dictionary family:
  father: str,
  mother: str,

  # optional key start
  son1: str,
  daughter1: str,
  son2: str,
  daughter2: str,
  # arbitrary many more sons, daughters, grandparents, ...
```

The `family` can contain any one of them.

```
{father: "Bob", mother: "Alice"}
```

or

```
{father: "Bob", mother: "Alice", son1: "Peter"}
```

or

```
{father: "Bob", mother: "Alice", daughter1: "Jane"}
```

If I just use `Dict[str, str]`, users cannot know `father` and `mother` are required. If I use a `TypedDict`, no additional keys are allowed; `total=False` and `NotRequired[str]` still require to know all keys up-front. How to type this?

---

In TypeScript on would use

```
type family = {
  father: string,
  mother: string,

  [key: string]: string
}
```

to allow *arbitrary* additional keys of type `string`.

Does Python have this function?

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0589/

Comment: See https://peps.python.org/pep-0655 - Marking individual TypedDict items as required or potentially-missing

Comment: The question is updated.

Comment: The `optional` or `NotRequired` keyword are mapped to TypeScript question mark. However, I want a more general one. If I don't know the actual keys, how do I define it? I only know `family` contains at least `father` and `mother`. The provider can put un-determined keys into it. The consumer knows it at least contains `father` and `mother`.

Comment: Do you want *arbitrary* additional items, i.e. the intersection of a TypeDict and a Dict[str, str]?

Comment: Yes, I want arbitrary additional items like Dict[str, str] and intersect with required ones like TypeDict.